# Example of a subalgebra of $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ that is not a direct summand

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field, and consider the finitely generated algebra $S = k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$. Is there an example of a subalgebra $R\subset S$ that is not a direct summand in the sense that there is a map of modules $\phi: S \rightarrow R$ that preserves degrees and each element of $R$ to itself?

If $R$ is indeed a direct summand, then Hilbert proved that $R$ is also finitely generated. What happens if that is not the case?

Comment: Try $S=k[t]$ and $R=k[t^2,t^3]$.

Comment: Maybe Mohan's hint is too succinct. If $R\subset S$ is a direct summand, then $IS\cap R=I$ for any ideal $I\subset R$. Now choose two ideals $I_1\subsetneq I_2$ in $R$ such that $I_1S=I_2S$.

Answer (score 0):

Your question reminds me of Hilbert's 14th problem. Given an algebraic group acting on a polynomial ring, one asks:

> Is the ring of invariants of this group always finitely generated?

Alas, the answer is no, and is due to Nagata. [The counter example is briefly stated in the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert's_fourteenth_problem#Nagata.27s_counterexample).

So, in general, one cannot conclude that a subalgebra of a polynomial ring is finitely generated.